# CORS configuration with Node.js to Python backend

Tags: python, node.js, https, server, cross-domain

I have a Node backend that, when called, needs to make a seperate request to a Python backend to make image classification predictions. The call works perfectly when running both servers locally but throws a 503 error when hosted.

The Node server receives a multipart/form-data image, then resends it to the Python server. Again, the entire route call works locally. I also tested the Python backend with Postman and it works fine.

Both servers are hosted on Heroku. The Node server is running v8.1.4 and the Python server is running v3.5.6

Here is the Python code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

# prediction route
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
@cross_origin()
def predict():
    req_image = request.files['image']
    # do stuff with req_image
    return prediction

#hosted locally for testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 3001))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

and the Node code:

```
const config = require('../config/main');
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const express = require('express');
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer()
var predictionRouter = express.Router();

predictionRouter.use(upload.single('image'));
predictionRouter.post('/predict', function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file)
    throw new NoDataError('No image provided');

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', req.file.buffer, {
    filename: 'image.png'
  });

  return axios.post(`${config.model.api_base_url}/predict`, formData, {
    headers: formData.getHeaders()
  })
  .then(results => res.status(200).send({ prediction: results.data }))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    next(err)
  });
});
```

Here is the Python error:

```
2018-09-19T19:03:14.520797+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/predict" host=python-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=2dbaa4f2-3d58-4f84-ba60-83cf721fd803 fwd="130.15.59.3" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=103ms status=503 bytes=379 protocol=https
2018-09-19T19:03:14.434838+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.157.202.232 - - [19/Sep/2018:19:03:14 +0000] "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 400 192 "-" "axios/0.18.0"
```

and the ugly Node error:

```
{ Error: Request failed with status code 503
    at createError (/project/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/project/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/project/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
  config:
   { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
     transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------087672685077373181485002',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0' },
     method: 'post',
     url: 'https://python-backend.herokuapp.com/predict',
     data:
      FormData {
        _overheadLength: 151,
        _valueLength: 38528,
        _valuesToMeasure: [],
        writable: false,
        readable: true,
        dataSize: 0,
        maxDataSize: 2097152,
        pauseStreams: true,
        _released: true,
        _streams: [],
        _currentStream: null,
        _boundary: '--------------------------087672685077373181485002',
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0 } },
  request:
   ClientRequest {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { socket: [Function],
        abort: [Function],
        aborted: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        timeout: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 6,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: true,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: undefined,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'python-backend.herokuapp.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 39047,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 45,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 710 },
     connection:
      TLSSocket {
        _tlsOptions: [Object],
        _secureEstablished: true,
        _securePending: false,
        _newSessionPending: false,
        _controlReleased: true,
        _SNICallback: null,
        servername: null,
        npnProtocol: undefined,
        alpnProtocol: false,
        authorized: true,
        authorizationError: null,
        encrypted: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 9,
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'python-backend.herokuapp.com',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 39047,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: undefined,
        _server: null,
        ssl: null,
        _requestCert: true,
        _rejectUnauthorized: true,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 45,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 710 },
     _header: 'POST /predict HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------087672685077373181485002\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nHost: python-backend.herokuapp.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent:
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 443,
        protocol: 'https:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256,
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: [Object] },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'POST',
     path: '/predict',
     _ended: true,
     res:
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Array],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 503,
        statusMessage: 'Service Unavailable',
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Circular],
        responseUrl: 'https://python-backend.herokuapp.com/predict',
        redirects: [],
        read: [Function] },
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     _redirectable:
      Writable {
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _options: [Object],
        _redirectCount: 0,
        _redirects: [],
        _requestBodyLength: 38735,
        _requestBodyBuffers: [],
        _onNativeResponse: [Function],
        _currentRequest: [Circular],
        _currentUrl: 'https://python-backend.herokuapp.com/predict' },
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]:
      { accept: [Array],
        'content-type': [Array],
        'user-agent': [Array],
        host: [Array] } },
  response:
   { status: 503,
     statusText: 'Service Unavailable',
     headers:
      { connection: 'close',
        server: 'Cowboy',
        date: 'Wed, 19 Sep 2018 19:03:14 GMT',
        'content-length': '506',
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store' },
     config:
      { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
        transformRequest: [Object],
        transformResponse: [Object],
        timeout: 0,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        headers: [Object],
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://python-backend.herokuapp.com/predict',
        data: [Object] },
     request:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: true,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /predict HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------087672685077373181485002\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nHost: python-backend.herokuapp.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/predict',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Object],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Object],
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n\t<html>\n\t  <head>\n\t\t<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">\n\t\t<meta charset="utf-8">\n\t\t<title>Application Error</title>\n\t\t<style media="screen">\n\t\t  html,body,iframe {\n\t\t\tmargin: 0;\n\t\t\tpadding: 0;\n\t\t  }\n\t\t  html,body {\n\t\t\theight: 100%;\n\t\t\toverflow: hidden;\n\t\t  }\n\t\t  iframe {\n\t\t\twidth: 100%;\n\t\t\theight: 100%;\n\t\t\tborder: 0;\n\t\t  }\n\t\t</style>\n\t  </head>\n\t  <body>\n\t\t<iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>\n\t  </body>\n\t</html>' } }
Error: Request failed with status code 503
    at createError (/project/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/project/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/project/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
POST /api/predictions/predict 500 443.837 ms - 74
```

Comment: There’s actually no CORS error. The CORS protocol is only involved in requests made by browsers and initiated from XHR/Fetch/Ajax calls from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Do you have an idea what could be the issue?

Comment: I dunno but I see *Request failed with status code 503*. A 503 is a “service unavailable” error, and typically just indicates some problem outside your application code — just that the service is unreachable at all from whatever code you’re trying to reach it from. And I see *Server Request Interrupted* logged on the python side. Neither of those error messages seem like cases where the request is even reaching your application code at all

Comment: I've found that the Python backend will respond fine to a request made by Postman, but for some reason when it's called from Axios in the Node backend it fails

Comment: @FrancescoVirga did you able to fix the issue?